# Why it shows different “clientWidth” value just because I set the “setInterval” function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have tried to get the `clientWidth` value to know the width of the body. But I found a question:

Below is the original code:

```
<input type="text" id="width"><br/>
<input type="text" id="height">
<script>
function getScreenSize(){
    document.getElementById("width").value= document.body.clientWidth;
    document.getElementById("height").value= document.body.clientHeight;
}
getScreenSize();
</script>


<div style="margin-top: 5300px;">foot</div>
```

And when I only change `getScreenSize();` into `setInterval("getScreenSize()",10);`, like below:

```
<input type="text" id="width"><br/>
<input type="text" id="height">
<script>
function getScreenSize(){
    document.getElementById("width").value= document.body.clientWidth;
    document.getElementById("height").value= document.body.clientHeight;
}
setInterval("getScreenSize()",10);
</script>


<div style="margin-top: 5300px;">foot</div>
```

Without any reason, the value of `clientWidth` changed.

Does anyone know why it changed just because I set the `setInterval` function?

Comment: what are the values your function is returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because without the setInterval, your `script` runs before the `div` at the bottom is added.

So when the browser reads your page, it runs the script and afterwards adds the bottom div, at the moment of run the width and height don't account for the `div`. 
With the `setInterval`, it accounts for that `div`.

Moving the script to the bottom will present same response from both ways.

```
<input type="text" id="width"><br/>
<input type="text" id="height">
<div style="margin-top: 5300px;">foot</div>
<script>
function getScreenSize(){
    document.getElementById("width").value= document.body.clientWidth;
    document.getElementById("height").value= document.body.clientHeight;
}
getScreenSize();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script is likely running before the page is completely rendered, thus the size of the page can actually change.  You need to insure that your code runs after the DOM (Document Object Model) is done (see [window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready) for more info).